# How to have a different thumbnail image from featured image in a Wordpress blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, image

On a Wordpress site I am maintaining, the client wants to have a different header image for the blog post than what appears in the thumbnail on the blog roll page and wherever the thumbnail to the blog post appears on the site.

Right now it seems that the featured image is used for both the header image and the thumbnail.

Is there a way where these images can be different?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, with lots of answers. One way to do this would be to use a custom meta field to hold the path to a banner image.

Comment: As @rnevius said, there's several ways you could do this, depending on: what theme are you currently using? Are you able to create a child theme? Are you happy to use a plugin?

Comment: This was passed on to me from another dev. I am only decent at wordpress also so it would be nice if it was a plugin. It is a custom theme built off supersimple framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this through your theme files or if you develop a plugin, it is not easy to explain it here. But you can use a plugin and do this easily.
1. "Multiple Post Thumbnails" plugin. Install this on your site ( or download this file and include it on your functions.php file https://github.com/voceconnect/multi-post-thumbnails/blob/master/multi-post-thumbnails.php ) and add following code to use another post image.

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(
        array(
            'label' => 'Secondary Image',
            'id' => 'secondary-image',
            'post_type' => 'post'
        )
    );
}
```

After that you can call for images using,

```
get_the_post_thumbnail($post_type, $thumb_id, $post_id, $size, $attr, $link_to_original);
```

And also you can use `add_image_size( $size_id, $width, $height, $hard_crop );`
function to specify  the size of the image.

2. "Advanced Custom Field" Plugin
   Using this plugin you can do many more things. And you can add any numbers of post thumbnails using this. And almost all the other custom input types can be easily add to your theme.

Comment: or just add a little code in your `functions.php` file with a couple of hooks (see [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)) to dynamicaly change thumbnail image

Comment: Not too familiar with PHP so I tried the Multiple Post Thumbnail plugin. I added the code to the plugin and the secondary image field shows up on the blog post entry but it still showing the featured image as the thumbnail. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You're going to need to modify your page template in order for something different to appear on the frontend.

Comment: I have edited the answer to match your need as you are going to use 'MultiPostThumbnails' in your theme